# How to send list of Objects to View and back to Post method in controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, post

Suppose I have class `Person`, I made a list of `Person` instances and add this list to a `Model`.

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
model.addAttribute("persons",persons);
return "savePersons";
```

In the `View` page I have a form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="savePerson" modelAttribute="persons">
    <c:forEach var="person" items="${persons}">
        <form:input path="person.FName" name="FName" id="FName" value="" />
        <form:input path="person.LName" name="LName" id="LName" value="" />
    </c:forEach>

    <button type="submit"></button>
</form:form>
```

When I click on the submit button I want to bind the `Person List` to the POST method on the controller..

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "savePerson" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePerson(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session,@ModelAttribute("persons")List<Person> persons) {
    System.out.println(persons.length);
    return "success";
}
```

but the `persons` list is not binding/fetching at the `POST` method.

Is it possible to bind a list objects in this way or is there an alternative for this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think this link will help you set up what you are trying to do:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/

It looks like in your form you need to modify it to something like:

```
<form:form method="post" action="savePerson" modelAttribute="persons">
    <c:forEach var="person" items="${persons}" varStatus="status">
        <form:input path="person[${status.index}].FName" name="FName" id="FName" value="" />
        <form:input path="person[${status.index}].LName" name="LName" id="LName" value="" />
    </c:forEach>
```

This SO question has a pretty good example that might help you out too: [List<Foo> as form backing object using spring 3 mvc, correct syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax?rq=1)

Comment: Link suggested by @ssn771 is very nice and simple for understand.Thanks ssn771.

Comment: Just wondering is it persons (with a s) for the form:input path statement? persons[${status.index}]

Comment: But this gets failed if the list size is more than 256.

Comment: @Shri, Sorry for late reply I don't know whether you solved error or not but you have to write code at controller in `init()` to avoid this.

Comment: @Amogh What to write in init(), which part of the code you are talking about,.

Comment: @Shri, Answer is added for that code. sorry I mentioned init() in my comment actually it's `@initBinder`

Comment: I agree with @Maximus - paths should be to `persons[${status....` not `person[${status...`.

Comment: The Viralpatel link : this is causing null pointer exception at controller Check this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764487/list-of-object-is-not-going-in-post-request

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why do I get this explicit url after submiting the form : 
saveUrl?objects[0].attribute1=value&objects[0].attribute2=value&objects[0].attribute3=value&objects[1].attribute1=value&objects[1].attribute2=value&objects[1].attribute3=value .. etc and the endpoint isn't called in the end

Answer (score 23):

As Shri mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480397/how-to-send-list-of-object-to-view-and-back-to-post-method-in-controller/15481311?noredirect=1#comment38294749_15481311) on ssn771 answer that if your binding list is more then 256 then it gives error like

> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException : Invalid property
>   'mylist[256]' of bean class [com.app.MyPageListVO]: Index of out of
>   bounds in property path 'mylist[256]'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256 at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPrope
>   rtyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:830) at...

This error occurs because by default 256 is limit for array and collection auto-growing to avoid  `OutOfMemoryErrors`, But you can increase this limit  by setting WebDataBinder's AutoGrowCollectionLimit property in `@InitBinder` in that controller.

Code:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    // this will allow 500 size of array.
    dataBinder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(500);
}
```