# Sending a list of objects from view to controller : limited to 256 objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, post

I've got a form in my view which send objects to my controller, but the matter is that I've got an exception if I send more than 256 objects :

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'followers[256]' of bean class [org.myec3.portalgen.plugins.newsletter.dto.FollowerFileDto]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'followers[256]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256
```

So I was wondering why such a limit, and I found this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24699008/4173394

But it doesnt seem to work for me (probably a bad use from me).

Here is my structure :
My view is called createUpdate.vm and post my form like this :

```
<form id="createFollowerFileForm" method="post" action="#route("followerFileController.upsertFollowerFile")" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form_styled">
```

My function upsertFollowerFile in FollowerFileController :

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        // this will allow 500 size of array.
        dataBinder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(500);
    }

    @Secured({ "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN_PORTALGEN", "ROLE_CUSTOMER_PORTALGEN", "ROLE_ADMIN_PORTALGEN", "ROLE_WRITER_PORTALGEN" })
    public String upsertFollowerFile(
            @ModelAttribute(value = "followerFile") FollowerFileDto followerFileDto,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

And my class FollowerFileDto :

```
public class FollowerFileDto {

    private String title;

    private Long followerId;

    private boolean isDeletable;

    private List<FollowerDto> followers;

    public FollowerFileDto() {
        this.followers = new ArrayList<FollowerDto>();
    }
```

As you can see in my controller, I tried to set more than 256 allowed objects (500) with the @InitBinder annotation, but it doesnt work at all. The InitBinder function is never called. Did I do anything wrong ?
Thanks for you answers ;)

Comment: You could try an initBinder without the Secured annotation. Should not that be for upserFollowerFile?

Comment: I tried to comment the @Secured, but I had the same problem.

Comment: Do you really need multipart/form-data?

Comment: Probably not. I tried without the multipart/form-data, and it worked the same : OK for less than 256, and same stack trace for more than 257.

Comment: Could you specify in you're initial question the RequestMapping method you're using please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the @InitBinder was not read, that's why new collection limit was not set. I had to upgrade my springmvc-router version to 1.2.0 (which also forced me upgrade my spring version to 3.2).

After those upgrades, with the same code, it works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Spring allow only 255 Objects in a list from `<form action="...">` to `@Controller` to avoid `OutOfMemory` problem. To increase this limit add `binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(1000)` in `initBinder()` method. `WebDataBinder` is a DataBinder that binds request parameter to JavaBean objects. The `initBinder()` method must be put in `Controller` or parent of the `Controller`.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(1000);

    // SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    // dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    // binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Comment: Right on the spot. Thank you for the answer.