# what are best coding practise to transfer the data from form to the servlet or spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

all the html forms submit the input parameters in string. do we have any standards to transfer the data to the servlet.

ex. I want to sent a String[][] 2d array which contains `{{"name:test","value="test" }{"name=test1","value=value2", "description=sample description"}}`}

Now I am sending the value in |test,test|test1,value2,sample description| and in the spring controller parsing the data using "|" as delimiter.

Do we any other of sending the request from the html form to the servlet?

Comment: you can read this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them

Comment: or you can read this, it's better to use a list of bean no ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480397/how-to-send-list-of-object-to-view-and-back-to-post-method-in-controller

Comment: thanks vincent which i am looking for.