# values in multiple tables spring validation prob

Tags: java, spring, validation, multiple-tables

I have problems to use multiple database tables
what I have:

Input:User (table User)
Inputfeld:Email(table User)
Input:Bookingnumber(table Bookingnumber)

using only inputfields form "user" works, adding bookingnumber from other table throws this error:

```
Invalid target for Validator     [shuttleservice.form.validator.UserFormValidator@1588512]:   shuttleservice.form.model.Bookingnumber@18d7616
```

the problem is simmilar to
[How insert values to multiple tables using spring and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711002/how-insert-values-to-multiple-tables-using-spring-and-hibernate)

and
[Invalid target for Validator in spring error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569939/invalid-target-for-validator-in-spring-error)

I have just two forms
one output, shows just the db data
one input with field for several db tables

should I use more than one validator?

```
// show add user form
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddUserForm(Model model) {

    logger.debug("showAddUserForm()");

    User user = new User();
    Bookingnumber bookingnumber = new Bookingnumber();

    // set default value
    user.setName("setNewUserName");     
    user.setEmail("test123@gmail.com");

    bookingnumber.setBookingnumber("123.456");

    model.addAttribute("userForm", user);
    //model.addAttribute("bookingnumberForm", bookingnumber);
    model.addAttribute("userForm", bookingnumber);


    populateDefaultModel(model);
System.out.println("#8");
    return "users/userform";

}
```

Comment: maybe solved.
with two validators, each one for each db table and in controller two initBinder. but I do not understand why I need more than one validator...
It is one *.jsp with inputfields to be checked. It's code bloat for me

I would have ~6 Tables later -> 6 Validatorclasses
+1 Validator for email expression check
+ more for other dynamic stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one model class to wrap all your form fields and pass object of this new wrapper class to your form. Then write a single validator class to validate the fields.

```
private class FormModel {
    private User user;
    private BookingNumber bookingNumber;

    //Getter Setter ....
}

// show add user form
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddUserForm(Model model) {

    logger.debug("showAddUserForm()");
    FormModel formModel = new FormModel ();
    User user = new User();
    Bookingnumber bookingnumber = new Bookingnumber();

    // set default value
    user.setName("setNewUserName");     
    user.setEmail("test123@gmail.com");

    bookingnumber.setBookingnumber("123.456");
    formModel.setUser(user);
    formModel.setBookingNumber(bookingNumber);
    model.addAttribute("formModel", formModel);
    return "users/userform";
}
```

Comment: thx.
I have 
@Override
 public String toString() {
  return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email +  "]" + isNew();
 }

and ...return "Bookingnumber [bookingnumber=" + bookingnumber +  "]" ; in the other Model and more in other model

how to handle it in a wrapper class? just glue together?

Comment: public String toString() {
        return "FormModel[" +
                "user=" + user +
                ", bookingNumber=" + bookingNumber +
                ']';
    }