# How to send list of items from JSP back to Controller in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

I'm trying to display list of questions on JSP page and using the check-box to select and submit them back to controller.
I can display them without any problem but when they're Posted back 'QuestionsListWrapper' is Null. Can someone point to me where I'm going wrong.

Entity Question

```
    public class Questions implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer quesId;
    
    @Transient
    private boolean isSelected;
```

Wrapper class

```
    public class QuestionsListWrapper {

        private List<Questions> quesWrapperList;

        public List<Questions> getQuesWrapperList() {
            return quesWrapperList;
        }

        public void setQuesWrapperList(List<Questions> quesWrapperList) {
            this.quesWrapperList = quesWrapperList;
        }
```

Controller Get

```
    @GetMapping("/group/{id}")
    public String showForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {

        Assessments ass = as.getAssById(id);        
        List<Questions> qlist = qs.getQuesByAssessment(ass);
        
        QuestionsListWrapper qlw = new QuestionsListWrapper();
        qlw.setQuesWrapperList(qlist);
        
        model.addAttribute("questions", qlw.getQuesWrapperList());
        return "stuEssay";
```

Controller Post

```
        @PostMapping("/saveSelectedQuestions")
```

//Here questions is null

```
        public String saveSelectedQuestions(@ModelAttribute("questions") QuestionsListWrapper questions, Model model) {
        
        List<Questions> selected = questions.getQuesWrapperList();
        
        System.out.println(questions.toString());
        System.out.println(questions.getQuesWrapperList());
        
        return "redirect:/studentHome";
```

JSP

```
      <form:form action="/saveSelectedQuestions" method="post" modelAttribute="questions">

            <c:forEach items="${questions}" var="question" varStatus="count">
            
                <input type="hidden" name="quesId" value="${question.quesId}">
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        
                        <textarea rows="3" >${question.quesText}</textarea>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="isSelected[${count.count}]"/>
                    </div>
            
            </c:forEach><!-- End of question list -->
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form:form>
```

Comment: I think there is problem in your input names that's the reason values are not getting to controller .Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480397/how-to-send-list-of-objects-to-view-and-back-to-post-method-in-controller) might help.