# Save a main object with a list object that is not in the main object

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to save an `object C` from a form. This form contains of two select drop downs each represents `class A` and `class B`.
`Class C` has a connection to `class A` and `class A` has a list connection to `class B`.

When I save `object C` from form I choose one item from select drop down `class A` and one item from `class B`. 
The new ID of `C` and the choosen ID of `A` is saved to a db table `db_C` and choosen ID of `B` is supposed to be saved together with newly created ID of `C` and a new ID of `D` to a db table `db_D` which contains connections to `B` and `C`.

Table db_A

```
__A__
  1  
  2  
  3
```

Table db_B

```
__B__|__C__
  4  |  2
  5  |  1
```

Table db_C

```
__C__|__A__
  1  |  2
  2  |  3
```

Table db_D

```
__D__|__B__|__C__
  1     2     1
```

I have a controller of C:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("listOfAs", listOfAs());
    model.addAttribute("C", new C());
    model.addAttribute("listOfBs", listOfBs());

    return "C/edit";
}

private List<B> listOfBs() {
    List<B> listOfBs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        listOfBs.addAll(BService.listBs());
    } catch(DataAccessException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return listOfBs;
}

private List<A> listOfAs() {
    List<A> listOfAs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        listOfAs.addAll(AService.listAs());
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return listOfAs;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(Model model, @ModelAttribute("C") C C, BindingResult CResult) {
    C.setA(AService.getA(C.getA().getID()));

    System.out.println(C.getA().getBs().isEmpty()); //Prints "True"

    if (C.getID() == 0) {
        CService.save(C);
    } else {
        CService.update(C.getID(), C);
    }
    return "redirect:/mvc/C/viewList";
}
```

And my form of C

```
<s:url value="/mvc/C/save" var="actionUrl" />
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="C" action="${actionUrl}">
    <fieldset>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="A">A:</label></th>
                <td><sf:select path="A.ID">
                        <sf:option value="0">&nbsp;</sf:option>
                        <sf:options items="${listOfAs}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="ID" />
                    </sf:select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="B">B:</label></th>
                <td>
                    <sf:select path="A.listRefToB">
                        <sf:option value="0">&nbsp;</sf:option>
                        <sf:options items="${listOfBs}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="ID" />
                    </sf:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input id="saveButton" class="right" type="submit" title="Save" value=" [ Save ] " />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</sf:form>
```

The problem is that when I save I get an empty list of `Bs`. I think it's because `C` doesn't have a direct reference to `B`. But I'm not sure. I really need help with this! How do get selected value of `B` into the save-function??

I've tried these two links with no result

[List<Foo> as form backing object using spring 3 mvc, correct syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax?rq=1)

[How to send list of Objects to View and back to Post method in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480397/how-to-send-list-of-object-to-view-and-back-to-post-method-in-controller)

I didn't get the names and id's into the optiontag.

The goal in this is to choose `A` and `B` in the form for `C` and on save I'd like to save all values I enter in form to `db_C` and `db_D` respectivly.

I hope someone can help me :)

I edited the question because the first one was a bit confusing.

Comment: No one? Really?Is this not possible or does it not make sense why I want to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new class AFormatter with a print and a parse function. That did the trick!