# Converting spring request body to list of objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a HTTP form that returns a following HttpRequest request body as follows

```
propertyName0=name0&propertyValue0=value0&propertyDescription0=description0&
propertyName1=name1&propertyValue1=value1&propertyDescription1=description1&propertyName2=name2&propertyValue2=value2&propertyDescription1=description2
```

I have a model that has the following properties

```
public class Property {

  private String propertyName;

  private String propertyValue;

  private String propertyDescription;

  // Getters and setters
}
```

I would like to be able to convert request body variables to a list of Property objects. Is there a way to do that?

My controller code (proposed)

```
@RequestMapping(value="update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void update(List<Property> properties) {
   // Do something with properties.
}

@RequestMapping(value="/fetch/}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String searchConfigProperties() throws Exception {
  List<Property> properties = // Some code that generates a list. model.
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  return gson.toJson(properties);
}
```

**UPDATE** The controller represents the service architecture back end code and is not necessarily intended to bind to any view.

Comment: You can use @ModelAttribute

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. What does your form contain? What's your domain model?

Comment: You should show your form : you will have to slightly modify it to make use of Spring MVC magic.

Comment: I have updated the code to add controller objects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax

Comment: You could generate list of model class objects. but you need to use `ModelAttribute` to access them in your form

Comment: @jakub.petr Your suggested solution binds a controller to a JSP view. I am a service architecture backend code that can be used by other views such as IOS or Android views. What would you advise?

Comment: JSP is there just for generating html code. You can achieve the same result if you would send the data from IOS/Androd/whatever else. It is just HTTP request in some structure. But in your case I would advice JSON(so obviously REST API). It is efficient, easy to construct on any device/platform(JS in browser) and you have then a nice API.

Comment: Is the number of properties constant (allways 3) or variable ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, Spring would do it automagically if you had :

```
props[0].propertyName=name0&props[0].propertyValue=value0&props[0].propertyDescription=description0&
props[1].propertyName=name1&props[1].propertyValue=value1&props[1].propertyDescription=description1&props[2].propertyName=name2&props[2].propertyValue=value2&props[1].propertyDescription=description2
```

If you can modify your form to obtain such a string all will work fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would I do something like this?

Comment: @Kartik : You said *I have a HTTP form that returns a following HttpRequest request body*. So I suppose you have control on that form. I will be able to elaborate if you show this form.

Comment: Hi, Serge, There is no form. This is a backend as a service. The idea is to support a restful backend and return a serialized responses that views can handle. The views can be IOS/Android or browser web.

Comment: @Kartik: So it is an API. Can you modify it to require input in the format I propose ? If not I'm afraid this answer won't have much value :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson have jackson-mapper-asl and jackson-core-asl in your class path and use  `@ResponseBody` as follow

```
@RequestMapping(value="fetch", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<Property> searchConfigProperties() {
// Do something with properties.

 return properties;
}
```

**Updated**

Here are the dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: how do I define my dependency on Jackson? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Jackson API
`@RequestMapping(value="update", method=RequestMethod.POST)`
`@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)`
`public void update(@RequestBody List<Property> properties) {`
`// Do something with properties.`
`}`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How would I do something like this?

Comment: @Katrick If I understood correctly, it is needed to receive list of property from front end part, so it is needed to write ajax-query with data and url. For example:<br> `var persons = []`<br> `for (var i=0;i<5;i++){` <br> `persons.push(new Person("alex", i))`<br>`}`<br>`$.ajax({`<br>
`url: "/credentials",`<br>
`type: "POST",`<br>
`dataType: "json",`<br>
`data: $.toJSON(persons),`<br>
`contentType: "application/json",`<br>
`mimeType: application/json",`<br>
`success: function(data){`<br>
`alert(data);`<br>
`},`<br>
`error: function(data){`<br>
`alert("Error");`<br>
`}`<br>
`});`