# Dynamic form with multiple objects submission in Spring?

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have an Object `CreateProjectFormModel` as follows (I am using Spring 4).

```
public class CreateProjectFormModel {
    private Project project;
    private List<DUser> users;

    public CreateProjectFormModel() {
        this.project = new Project();
        this.users = new ArrayList<DUser>();
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public List<DUser> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<DUser> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to create Controller and a corresponding form so that multiple `DUser` can be submitted at once - can do it if the object does not consist of a collection?

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax), but I don't know how may users will be added to the project in advance, so cannot fix the users size.

I read through [thymeleaf tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html), but would be interested to know if can do without use of thymeleaf.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you posted in the question [List<Foo> as form backing object using spring 3 mvc, correct syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax) should provide a solution for you, what is discussed in the comments

> I assume that this solution requires having a fixed amount of input
>   fields, is that correct? What if you have a dynamic number of input
>   fields?

does not concern the number of users, which doesn't have to be fixed, rather it concerns the fact that that the properties of the object is differing, which I don't believe is your case. So, if your *DUser* has a property *userName*, and e.g. your *Project* has a property *name*. Your controller method could simply be,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(CreateProjectFormModel createProjectFormModel) {
       ...
}
```

and your form

```
<form:form action="/form/test" method="post">
    <div class="single">
        <input type="text" name="project.name"/>
        <input type="text" name="users[0].userName"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="addNewUserInputSection();return false">add another user</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form:form>
```

where you will have to provide some effort is to create a javascript function *addNewUserInputSection* that will add new set of input fields for the *users* property with an incremented index, e.g.

```
<form:form action="/form/test" method="post">
    <div class="single">
        <input type="text" name="project.name"/>
        <input type="text" name="users[0].userName"/>
        <input type="text" name="users[1].userName"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="addNewUserInputSection();return false">add another user</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form:form>
```

the examples are basic, but should be enough to have you resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer works, here's an alternate that does not require you to create a wrapper class/ form class.
**Model And Controller**

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private List<Foo> fooList;
    public Foo() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getFooList() {
        return fooList;
    }

    public void setFooList(String fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }

}

@Controller("/")
public class FooController{

    //returns the ModelAttribute fooListWrapper with the view fooForm
    @RequestMapping(value = "/FOO", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getFooForm(Model model) {
        List<Foo> fooList = service.getFooList();

        model.addAttribute("fooList", fooList);

        return "list_foo"; //name of the view
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/FOO", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postFooList(@ModelAttribute("foo")Foo foo, Model model) {
        List<Foo> list = foo.getFooList(); // **This is your desired object. 
        //If you debug this code, you can easily find this is the list of  
        //all the foo objects that you wanted, provided you pass them properly. 
        //Check the jsp file to see one of the ways of passing such a list of objects**
        //Rest of the code
    }

}
```

**JSP View**

```
<form:form id="form" action="<paste-target-url-here>" method="POST" modelAttribute="fooList">


    <c:forEach items="${fooList}" varStatus="i">
           <form:input path="fooList[${i.index}].name" type="text"/>
           <!-- Here you are setting the data in the appropriate index which will be caught in the controller -->
    </c:forEach>


    <button>submit</button>
</form:form>
```