# How to pass variable number of parameters from jsp page to the java controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a jsp page and a controller with fillowing functionality:

```js
 java controller code:

@Controller
public class AddNewItemController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/newItem/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getDataForInterval4(@RequestParam("itemId") String itemId, @RequestParam("product1SkusCnt") String product1SkusCnt, @RequestParam("itemName") String itemName, HttpServletRequest request) {

 return "ItemSubmitted";
}
}
```

```html
my main jsp file that submits to controller:

<center>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>How many items do you have?</td>
   <td> <input type="number" name="productsCnt" id="productsCnt" size="2" min="1" value="1" onchange="productCount()"/> </td> 
  </tr>
 </table>
</center>

<form action="/newItem/submit" method="post">
<br /><br />
<div id="outerDivContainer">
 <div id="product1Div" name="product1Div" >
  <hr /> Product 1 Name: <input id="product1Name" /> Product 1 ID: <input id="product1ID" /> How many SKUs of Product 1? <input id="product1SkusCnt" type="number" size="2" min="1" value="1" onchange="skusCount(1)"/> <br /><br />
  <div id="skusContainer1">
   <div id="sku1Div">
    SKU 1 Name: <input id="sku1"/>
   </div> <br />
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
<hr />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>

<script>
function productCount() {
 console.log("onchange product");
 document.getElementById('outerDivContainer').innerHTML = "";
 var cnt = document.getElementById('productsCnt').value;
    console.log("cnt="+cnt);
 for (i=0;i<cnt;i++){
  var newEl = document.createElement('div');
  newEl.class='prodRow';
  j=i+1;
     newEl.innerHTML = '<div id="product'+j+'Div"><hr /> Product '+j+' Name: <input id="product'+j+'Name" /> Product '+j+' ID: <input id="product'+j+'ID" /> How many SKUs of Product '+j+'? <input id="product'
       +j+'SkusCnt" type="number" size="2" min="1" value="1" onchange="skusCount('+
         j+')" /> <br /><br /> <div id="skusContainer'+j+'"><div id="sku1Div"> SKU 1 Name: <input id="sku1"/></div> <br /> </div></div>';
     document.getElementById('outerDivContainer').appendChild(newEl);
 } 

}

function skusCount(productId){
 console.log("onchange skus, product id= "+productId+";");
 var skusCnt = document.getElementById('product'+productId+'SkusCnt').value;
 console.log("skusCnt="+skusCnt);
 document.getElementById('skusContainer'+productId).innerHTML = "";
 for (i=0;i<skusCnt;i++){
  var newEl = document.createElement('div');
  newEl.class='skuRow';
  j=i+1;
     newEl.innerHTML = '<div id="sku'+j+'Div">SKU '+j+' Name: <input id="sku'+j+'" /> </div> <br />';
     document.getElementById('skusContainer'+productId).appendChild(newEl);
 } 
}

</script>
```

ItemSubmitted.jsp is just a jsp file that confirms successful item submission.
The problem is I don't know how many items will be passed to the controller, or how many skus each item might have. 
What would be a suggested approach to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are submitting param name `product1Name` and you are trying to read some other param

Comment: You are right, but this is not what I am asking in my question. I didn't try to run that code. I know it's not final yet. I need a hint from somebody who know how to approach the solution.

Comment: Yes, you can post list of object to mvc action.
Look at this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10518009/885152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is much simpler than I expected. All I have to do is just know how many parameters I will pass and their names. I don't have to specify it in the controller as `@RequestParam("itemId") String itemId, @RequestParam("product1SkusCnt")` etc.

Instead I should only pass a request as an argument:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/newItem/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getDataForInterval4(HttpServletRequest request) { return "ItemSubmitted"}`

I can call each of those passed parameters in the controller by doing the following:

`request.getParameter("product"+i+"SkusCnt"))`

Just need to make sure that I pass the total count of products also.

Hope this helps someone.