# How to bind input elements to an arraylist element in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp

How to bind input elements to an arraylist element in Spring MVC?

The view model:

```
public class AssigneesViewModel {

    private int evaluatorId;
    private int evaluatedId;
    private String evaluatorName;
    private String evalueatedName;
    //getters and setters
}
```

The model attribute:

```
public class AssignEvaluationForm{
   private ArrayList<AssigneesViewModel> options;
   public ArrayList<AssigneesViewModel> getOptions() {
      return options;
   }

   public void setOptions(ArrayList<AssigneesViewModel> options) {
      this.options = options;
   }
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="addAssignment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addAssignment(Model model){
     model.addAttribute("addAssignment", new AssignEvaluationForm());
     return "addAssignment";
}
```

Then in the jsp i have 4 hidden inputs which represent the fields for the evaluatedId, evaluatorId, evaluatorName, evaluatedName -> options[0]. 
How i am going to write the jsp code to map those inputs with an element of the arrayList?

Update:

```
<form:form commandName="addAssignment" modelAttribute="addAssignment" id="addAssignment" method="POST">
//..........
     <c:forEach items="${addAssignment.options}" var="option" varStatus="vs">
         <div id="assigneesOptions" >    
             <form:input path="addAssignment.options[${vs.index}].evaluatedId" value="1"></form:input>
         </div>
    </c:forEach>
 //..............
</form:form>
```

With this update i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'options[]' available as request attribute
```

Comment: Similar questions here.

[Follow this link][1]


[Alternate this one also][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480397/how-to-send-list-of-object-to-view-and-back-to-post-method-in-controller

Comment: @MizanurRahmanMojumder Thank you for your suggestion, but i have already implemented the answers from the related posts. I get Neither BindingResult exception. I updated the question. Clearly i make a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:input path="addAssignment.options[${vs.index}].evaluatedId" value="1"></form:input>
```

Instead of this `addAssignment.options[${vs.index}].evaluatedId`

Use this -> `option.evaluatedId`

Or you might reach value with arraylist get -> `${addAssignment.options.get(vs.index).evaluatedId}` , try to turn out that ${} jstl's call curly brackets. BTW i'm not sure this last example work on path="" attribute.

Comment: The array list of options is empty on GET method. Then the user is adding some inputs and on POST i want to save those inputs as options[0]. I am not sure that it is very clear. It is even possible?

Comment: Your question in your comment is irrelevant to your main question. If you want to send data as an array, in name attribute name="options[]" normally use on checkboxes and radio buttons. But you have a problem getting evaluatedId in your jsp.