# Spring MVC - Creating Custom List Dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a custom list from Spring MVC.

The main issue is I can't find any great sources on how to create a custom list... But here is the design I want and some code I have already.

**Design**
[image]

**Code**

JSP frontpage.jsp

```
<div id="result-panel">
            <ul>
            <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${offenderlists}">
                <li>OffenderId: <c:out value="${listValue.offenderId}"/> <li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Java controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String someMethod(@RequestParam("intelvalue") String valueOne) {
        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
            OffenderDAO offenderDAO = (OffenderDAO) context.getBean("offenderDAO");
            Offender[] offenders = null;

            try {
                offenders = offenderDAO.requestOffenders(valueOne);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            for(Offender o: offenders) 
                System.out.println("offender: "+ o.OffenderId);
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("frontpage");
            model.addObject("offenderlists", offenders);
            // Returned the list of offenders to jsp here...
            return "frontpage";
    }
```

I know I am doing it wrong I have in image url in the offender object along with everything I need I have no issues loading the offenders from my database. How do I create a list of offenders as show in design?

**QUESTION**
How to create what is show in design with Spring MVC Models? Offender objects are loaded and data is within the objects I just need to display in list form how would I go at doing such?

References below were viewed and didn't provide a good enough example/answer.
References: [List<Foo> as form backing object using spring 3 mvc, correct syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax?rq=1)

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the  didn't display is because I didn't return ModelAndView as the return value of the method name somemethod

Answer (score 0):

You may use a layout like in the fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/oahkou2f/

Instead of the text's, you can use values like `${listValue.property}`.

Comment: The main issue isn't how it's displayed its that I can't get  <c:out value="${listValue.offenderId}"/> to display anything

Comment: can't you simply give `${listValue.property}`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div id="result-panel">
   <ul>
      <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${offenderlists}">
         <li>OffenderId: ${listValue.offenderId}<li>
      </c:forEach>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. [Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)