# spring form jsp binding reference bean

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute, spring-form

I was trying to bind POJO using `spring form` tag library. After binding reference class bean variables, **I am getting "Bad Request Error- Http Status 400".**

If I remove binding of reference class, My form is submitted successfully and values are also populated inside the class.

```
public class EmployeeTourPojo {

  private String empDisplayName;

  private List<TourDetailsPojo> tourDetails;

  //getter and setter

}
```

and

```
public class TourDetailsPojo {

    private Date departDate;

    private String departTime;

//getters and setters

}
```

JSP:

```
<td><form:input path="empDisplayName" class="form-control"/>    </td>

<form:input placeholder="Departure Date" path="tourDetails[${index}].departDate" required="required" class="datepicker form-control"/><br/>
```

I had got references from few [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480397/how-to-send-list-of-objects-to-view-and-back-to-post-method-in-controller) but they are loading the list of reference bean at the get request while I am adding the rows before the submitting the JSP.

[image]

Comment: How is the index being populated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax/42478349#42478349
This might solve your problem.

Comment: Please publish your controller. I guess that the problem lies in there.

Comment: how your first  input div is generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue lies in incrementing the index after Clicking "Add Row". Hence, I had added following JQuery code to increment index.

```
$("#addRow").click(function(){
                    //alert("The button was clicked.");
                    var addressRow = $('.repeat-address').last();
                    var addressRowLength = $('.repeat-address').length;

                    var newAddressRow = addressRow.clone(true).find("input").val("").end(); 

                    $(newAddressRow).find("td input,td select").each(function(index,item) {
                        item.name = item.name.replace(/[0-9]/g,addressRowLength);
                    });

                    newAddressRow.insertAfter(addressRow);


                });
```

HTML CODE

```
<c:set var="index" value="0"/>
                    <td><form:input path="empDisplayName" class="form-control"/>    </td>
                    <tr class="repeat-address">

                        <td>Departure Date</td>
                        <td><form:input placeholder="Departure Date" path="tourDetails[${index}].departDate" required="required" class="datepicker form-control"/></td>


                        <td>Pincode</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tourDetails[${index}].departDate"/></td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="tourDetails[${index}].tourTicket"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="3"><input id="addRow" type="button" value="Add Row"></td></tr>
```

Since, I also need to bind input type file with POJO. I had also Added one Multipart field (in TourDetailsPojo  Bean) as

```
private Date departDate;

private Multipart tourTicket;

//getters and setters
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL tag library to iterate data from list.

```
<c:forEach var="tourDetails" items="${tourDetails}" varStatus="status">
<form:input placeholder="Departure Date" path="tourDetails[${status.index}].departDate" required="required" class="datepicker form-control"/><br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Also add below taglib at starting of your JSP.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: as I mentioned, my input div is generated dynamically (using add row on jsp). So I cannot use for loop to bind input variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly this will help you

1. Inspect your table row `<tr>` tag in browser
2. Copy the **html** element, to make it as **template**, in inspected element **Right Click** and **Copy** -> **Outer HTML**.
   Suppose Generated HTML element looks like as below

   **this**  will convert

   ...`<form:input placeholder="Departure Date" path="tourDetails[${index}].departDate" required="required" class="datepicker form-control"/><br/>`...

   to something like **this**

   ...`<input placeholder="Departure Date" id="tourDetails0.departDate" name="tourDetails[0].departDate" required="required" class="datepicker form-control"/><br/>`...
3. Create **template** of generated html

   var template = '...`<input placeholder="Departure Date"
   id="tourDetails{INDEX}.departDate" name="tourDetails[{INDEX}].departDate"
   required="required" class="datepicker form-control"/><br/>`...';

   See I have replace `0` with `{INDEX}`
4. On `Add Row` button click, get `length` of `<tr>`, replace `{INDEX}` with length, using javascript function
   `generated_template = template.replace(/{INDEX}/g,length);`
5. Append `generated_template` to table.

Hope this will help...

Comment: please let me know why downvote so, I will delete/change answer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems error in generating in dynamic index after add row. however, still needs to test more on it.