# Map a dynamic list of inputs to Model Attribute in Spring MVC from JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Similar to this question here: [List<Foo> as form backing object using Spring 3 MVC, correct syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617207/listfoo-as-form-backing-object-using-spring-3-mvc-correct-syntax)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/FOO", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getSendEmail(List<Foo> foos, Model model) {
    // ...
}

<form:form id="frmFoo" modelAttribute="foos">
   <c:forEach items="${foos}" var="foo">
     <form:input path="${foo.name}" type="text"/>
```

I need to be able to take in a list as a model attribute when posting a form. All of the examples including the one above assume there will be existing entries in the list. But this will not be the case if a person is filling out a new form.

So my question is how do you post a list of model attribute dynamically when no entries of the list existed when you landed on the page. How do I dynamically create input that will map to a null or empty list of my model attribute.

Comment: Anyone? There must be a way to do this. I cannot imagine Spring hasn't thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Say you have a model (getters/setters omitted for brevity)

```
class SomeModel {
    List<SomeModelChildClass> children;
}

class SomeModelChildClass {
    String someString;
}
```

In your JSP you can do map to the children (even if its blank) like so...

This will map a SomeModelChildClass with someString = "I Did it!" when you post to your controller. This of course assumes you have a form and model attribute setup in the controller for SomeModel. Then you can post via the the input and it will populate your model with the list!